# Ending While loop with blank line(Enter key) inside SwitchCase

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement, blank-line

*amended input scan
I'm trying to end a while loop with enter key/blank line
Test codes below works fine.

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line;

    while ( (line=scan.nextLine()).length() > 0)  
    {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

However, when I integrate it within my main program(while loop placed within int switch case within a do-while loop) the program skips the codes @case2 and will continue do-while loop

```
int input;
do{
      System.out.print("Choose a function (-1 to exit): ");
      input=scan.nextInt();
      switch (input)
      {
          case 1:
          break;
          case 2:
          //same while loop here
          break;
      }

  }while(input!=-1);
```

Sample output:

```
Choose a function (-1 to exit): 1
Choose a function (-1 to exit): 2
//skip case2 coding
Choose a function (-1 to exit): 1
Choose a function (-1 to exit): -1
//program ends
```

Comment: Could you post your entire method body? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, especially where `input` is assigned.

Comment: you are not taking any input inside switch case.which turns to infinite loop

Comment: do while loop should ends with a `semicolon`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that scanner is not reading all input.  There's a blank line (a newline character) in the buffer when the Scanner starts to read, so it returns an empty line, which causes your line length to be 0 and exit the loop immediately.

Here's my best guess as to what your current program is:

```
public class InputTest
{

   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
      int input = 0;
      do {
         System.out.print( "Choose a function (-1 to exit): " );
         input = scan.nextInt();
         switch( input ) {
            case 1:
               System.out.println("..1");
               break;
            case 2:
               System.out.println("..2");
               //same while loop here
               String line = scan.nextLine();
               System.out.println(">>"+line+"<<");
               while( line.length() > 0 ) {
                  System.out.println( "  Read line: " + line );
                  line = scan.nextLine();
                  System.out.println(">>"+line+"<<");
               }
               break;
         }
      } while( input != -1 );
   }
}
```

And its output:

```
run:
Choose a function (-1 to exit): 1
..1
Choose a function (-1 to exit): 2
..2
>><<
Choose a function (-1 to exit): -1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 11 seconds)
```

You can see that the line prints as `>><<` which means it was read but empty.  I think the left over newline from '2' above, since a newline isn't part of the number 2 and would be left in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is not able to read any input as there is no tokens (after  you press 2) in current line .

You need to use scan.nextLine() (to ignore the rest of the currrent line and move the scanner to beginning of next line) before reading the input.

```
do{

      System.out.print("Choose a function (-1 to exit): ");
      input=scan.nextInt();       

      switch (input)
      {
      case 1:
         break;
      case 2:
         scan.nextLine();//skips the entire current line.
         while ( (line=scan.nextLine()).length() > 0)  
            {
            System.out.println(line);
            }
            //System.out.println(line.length());
            break;
         }
}while(input!=-1);
```

Output

```
Choose a function (-1 to exit): 2
hello
hello
bye
bye

Choose a function (-1 to exit):-1
```

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help! After some trial and error, I got the code to work

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int input;
  do{
  System.out.print("Choose a function (-1 to exit): ");
  input=scan.nextInt();       

  switch (input)
  {
  case 1:
     break;
  case 2:
     System.out.println("..2"); 
     String line;
     scan.nextLine();//skips the entire current line.
     while ( (line=scan.nextLine()).length() > 0)  
        {
        System.out.println(line);
        }
        break;
     }
  }while(input!=-1);
```

The System.out.println() seems to clear interference from scan.nextInt(),
The just my theory though

Comment: The problem was with the scanner as there were no tokens in current line after you entered 2.That is why you need to skip the current line and move to the  beginning of  next line to read the input.